# Display SQL query result on VB form

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am facing a problem displaying the result of my "select *" query on the form . Here is my code:

```
           Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=PARTH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;pwd=parth;database=college")

    myconnection.Open()
    mycommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from [demo3]",myconnection)
    Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(mycommand)
    Dim mydsStudent As New DataSet()

    DataGridView2.DataSource = mydsStudent
    Me.Controls.Add(DataGridView2)
    ra = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Data displayed" & ra)

    myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

But when I write this code and run my form I am not able to see any records present in my database tables being displayed on my form. I have inserted a DataGridView on my form . What changes should I do to my code ? Can Anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are working with a DataAdapter, you need to call the `Fill()` method for it to fill a `DataSet/DataTable`.  After you initialize the `DataSet`, make this call:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(mydsStudent)
```

Also, take out your `ExecuteNonQuery()` call.

EDIT: Try something like this.

```
Dim myconn As New SqlConnection(yourConnectionStringHere)
Dim myTable As New DataTable()
Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand()
myCmd.Connection = myconn
myCmd.CommandText = "select * from demo3"

Dim myAdapater As New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd)
myAdapter.Fill(myTable)

DataGridView2.DataSource = myTable
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot .. I tried ur code...I inserted mySQlDataAdapter.Fill(mydsstudent) after the line " Dim mystudent As New DataSet() " and also removed the executenonquery() line..still nothing is displayed on the form when I run the application

Comment: I am getting an error "myAdapter not declared " ..how to remove this error?